# Asymptotic solution of wrinkle amplitude

Tags: integration, asymptotics

I have encountered an equation determining amplitude of sinusoidal wrinkle

$\int_{0}^{\lambda_0} \sqrt{1+[(A_0\sin{\frac{2\pi x}{\lambda_0}})']^2} \,dx = \int_{0}^{\lambda_0(1+\epsilon_a)} \sqrt{1+[(A\sin{\frac{2\pi x}{\lambda_0(1+\epsilon_a)}})']^2} \,dx$
, where $\lambda_0=\frac{\pi h}{\sqrt{\epsilon_c}}  $

they say it has the asymptotic solution for $\frac{A_0}{\lambda_0} \ll 1$

$A=\sqrt{1+\epsilon_a}\sqrt{A_0^2-h^2\frac{\epsilon_a}{\epsilon_c}}$

I have no clue on it. How can I approach this kind of equation?

**Khang, D.-Y., Jiang, H., Huang, Y., & Rogers, J. A. (2006). A Stretchable Form of Single-Crystal Silicon for High-Performance Electronics on Rubber Substrates. Science, 311(January), 208–212.**

Comment: Both the LHS and RHS can be expressed in terms of elliptic integrals, e.g. the cammand of Mathematica `Integrate[
 Sqrt[1 + (A0*2*Pi/\[Lambda]0*Cos[2*Pi*x/\[Lambda]0])^2], {x, 
  0, \[Lambda]0}, Assumptions -> A0 > 0 && \[Lambda]0 > 0]` produces such an  output which is too long to be quoted here..

Comment: I assume that $A$ and the other parameters are independent of $x$. Executing the derivatives and a proper change of integration variables (i.e., $z=x 2 \pi /\lambda_0$ for the integral on the left hand side of the equation and similarly for the right hand side), you need to solve integrals of the form $\int_0^{2 \pi} \sqrt{1 + \beta^2 cos(z)^2} dz$ . You would get Elliptic functions for it, i.e., $4 E(-\beta^2)$. However, you do not need this for the asymptotic expansion. Just expand the square root under the integral to order $\beta^2$  and then execute the integral to get the desired result.